# Image validation. Minimum width. Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm trying to write a custom directive for input image validation. I would like to validate image chosen to have 'width' higher than X value (300 in the example).

```html
   

 <input id="imageFile" minWidth="300" minHeight="300" name="image" type="file" ngModel #image="ngModel">
<div *ngIf="image.invalid">
      <p *ngIf="image.errors.width" >width should be higher than 300px!</p>
</div>
```

My directive looks like this:

```js
import { Directive, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS, Validator, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[minWidth]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: ImageMinWidthDirective, multi: true}]
})
export class ImageMinWidthDirective implements Validator {
  @Input() minWidth: number;
  private width = 0;
  file: any;
  image: any;
  @HostListener('change', ['$event']) onChange($event) {
    const files = $event.target.files || $event.srcElement.files;
    this.file = files[0];
  }

  validate(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} {
    return this.minWidth ? this.minWidthValidator()(control)
      : null;
  }
  minWidthValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} => {
      this.image = new Image();
      this.image.onload = event => {
        this.width = event.path[0].width;
        alert(this.image.width);
      };

      this.image.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.file);
      return this.width < this.minWidth ? {'width': {value: 'hello'}} : null;
    };
  }
}
```

The problem is that converting from File to Image is async process, so my validator is completed before convertation and reading image.width is finished.
As the result, I have the validation lag: when I upload new image, validation is done to previous image.
What could be done in order to provide working validation here?

Comment: I think onload is never fired

Comment: @Vega, 'onload' is actually fired after we set 'image.src'. In debug mode I've checked that

Comment: And you get alert() too?

Comment: @Vega, yes, the width of loaded image is showing up.

Comment: @Vega, docs says that afterViewChecked hook works only with component, but not directive. So, what is the way to move code there as soon as it is related to directive field 'image'?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154121/discussion-between-vega-and-paul-andrusiak).